# Automatic theorem proving with term rewriting on finitely presented algebraic structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

I am looking for an open source software package that can do automatic theorem proving for finitely presented algebraic structures.  You should be able to program in the axioms of the structure and then give it a theorem, which I think is an equation, though I am not sure, and then it can try to prove this theorem.  Sorry if this is vague, but perhaps two or three examples might help me to see what is out there and what I could possibly use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving. It's not mentioned on that page but the late Bill McCune's prover9 is a particular favourite of mine and very easy to use - after 30 minutes learning it's syntax, you'll be good to go.